# Conflict of modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to show the content using pagination so I have used "angularUtils.directives.dirPagination" directive in module as angularJS doesn't support pagination inherently. Along with that I want to use angular strap so I can improve UX. To do so I have to put "mgcrea.ngStrap" directive. But when I use these both directives I don't get anything working out.
This is what I am doing.

```
   var xyz = angular.module('test', 
             ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','mgcrea.ngStrap']);

   xyz.controller('LoadConnectors', function ($scope) {
    ....
   });
```

Can any one help me out? I am really stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is an error??.please elaborate it more

Comment: When you use only one of them does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one solution for this problem

First make sure your js refrences are correct

Then make sure you include refrences for  'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','mgcrea.ngStrap' before js file which contains refrence for angular.module